# Wordpress after local to live some urls are still using local url

Tags: wordpress

Moved my wordpress website from local to online (subdomain),

I have changed **http://local/portfolio/** to live website **http://name.lastname.com** for context.
First I've done it with the .sql file, imported it and then found out some images didnt show up, so i tried the plugin "better search and replace" but that didnt work either. I found it weird that I see the correct src url in the .sql file but the source code still using localhost url.

Currently I have these img src values

`http://local/portfolio/wp-content/uploads/...` 
and would ofcourse want them linked to 
`http://name.lastname.com/wp-content/uploads/...`.

Nothing seems to work, 
any suggestions on what i could do?

Comment: Are the images inside the theme or in the uploads directory?

Comment: in the upload, they are in name.lastname.eu/portfolio/wp-content/uploads  but the some src images link to localhost/portfolio/wp-content/uploads